# VSCode - Implement Custom IntelliSense through Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, internationalization, intellisense, vscode-extensions, javascript-intellisense

I want to provide IntelliSense in VSCode based on a JSON file in the root folder of the project directory. The JSON file is at `./languages/english.json` and is a key-value pair like below:

```json
{
    "sidebar.title": "Hello",
    "sidebar.name": "John",
    "sidebar.surname": "Doe",
    "first.aaa": "Hello",
    "first.bbb": "Hi",
}
```

I want VSCode to suggest this JSON's keys whenever I'm writing in a function named `i18n()`.
Something like this:

[image: Intellisense]

I figured the best way to write a VSCode extension of my own. I've created one before, but how can I implement this feature?

P.S. I know about the option of using snippet json files directly, however those have the limitation of not being dynamically populated.

* Simillarly asked by [yansenlei](https://github.com/yansenlei) on [an issue on VSCode's repo #133001](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133001)

Comment: write a `CompletionItemProvider`, the only difficulty would be to determine if you are in an `i18n()` function

Comment: in the issue IllusionMH comments the same, what is the problem

Comment: @rioV8 to determine if you are in an i18n() function.

Comment: for that you need to analyze the source file and detect functions, arrow functions, .... and maybe you have to detect if you are IN a string, or you can just always suggest if the prefix is typed, you won't have a lot of false positives